# How do I programmatically change the create, modify, access date on a file?

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to change the modify date on a file on Windows so that it doesn't clutter up my sort order. How can I do that with a script (I may need to do that to the file in the future as well)?

BTW: I don't want to have to install applications to do this.

Comment: There is no existing way to do this from the command line. If you want to write code to do it then please express that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you have PowerShell:

```
$(Get-Item ).creationtime=$(Get-Date "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am/pm")
$(Get-Item ).lastaccesstime=$(Get-Date "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am/pm")
$(Get-Item ).lastwritetime=$(Get-Date "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am/pm")
```

Note that the correct date format string to use will depend on your localization, e.g. in the UK, the correct format string would be `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: Most likely that would involve installing something for him, but good answer none the less. +1

Comment: @EBGreen Powershell is built into Vista and Win7 and available from Microsoft.

Comment: @KansaiRobot the filename goes in the first `( )` after the `Get-Item`.  I edited the answer to reflect this.
And I've verified that this _does_ work

Comment: I'd advise against suggesting `nn/nn/yyyy` because of the date order ambiguity.  `yyyy/mm/dd` also works fine.

Answer (score 12):

Using PowerShell, the command would be:

```
PS C:\temp> (Get-Item Notes.txt).lastwritetime=$(Get-Date "1/2/2016 12:34 am")

PS C:\temp> (Get-Item Notes.txt).creationtime=$(Get-Date "1/2/2016 12:34 am")

PS C:\temp> (Get-Item Notes.txt).lastaccesstime=$(Get-Date "1/2/2016 12:34 am")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a VBScript example of changing the modification date:

```
Sub ChangeModifiedDate(strFolder, strFile, dteNew)

    Dim oShell
    Dim objFolder

    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oFolder = oShell.NameSpace(strFolder)
    oFolder.Items.Item(strFile).ModifyDate = dteNew
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked for me. I'm using Windows 2008 Server and signed in with admin access.

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell you can list the file and use that to set attributes on it in a single line.

For example with wildcard:

```
(ls yourF*).lastWriteTime = (get-date).AddDays(-60)
```

For a single file:

```
(ls yourFile.doc).creationTime = (get-date).AddDays(-60)
```

*(The above commands assume you have cd'd to the file's directory.)*

Answer (score 1):

Using Java you can do:

```
File file = new File("someFile");
file.setLastModified(long time);
```